# A java-based soap request returns always soap response with 0 as the value i need

Tags: java, soap, webservice-client

I am trying to send a soap request to an open webservice (webserviceX.NET currency converter). Here is my code:

```
String SOAP_REQUEST = "<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:SOAP=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><SOAP:Body><ConversionRate xmlns=\"http://www.webserviceX.NET/\"/>" +
        "<FromCurrency>EUR</FromCurrency><ToCurrency>ILS</ToCurrency></SOAP:Body></SOAP:Envelope>";



//  SOAPEnvelope env = new SOAPEnvelope();
//Create a Stream Source of the Request String
  byte[] reqBytes = SOAP_REQUEST.getBytes();
  ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(reqBytes);
  StreamSource ss = new StreamSource(bis);

  //Create a SOAP Message Object
  MessageFactoryImpl messageFactory = new MessageFactoryImpl();
  SOAPMessage msg = messageFactory.createMessage();
  SOAPPart soapPart = msg.getSOAPPart();

  //Set the soapPart Content with the stream source
  soapPart.setContent(ss);

  //Create a WebService Call
  Service service = new Service();
  Call call = (Call)service.createCall();
  call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new java.net.URL(endpoint));
  call.setProperty( Call.SOAPACTION_USE_PROPERTY, new Boolean( true ) );
  call.setProperty( Call.SOAPACTION_URI_PROPERTY, "http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConversionRate");
  call.setEncodingStyle("utf-8");

  //Invoke the WebService.
  SOAPEnvelope resp = call.invoke(((org.apache.axis.SOAPPart)soapPart).getAsSOAPEnvelope());
 ...
//then i parse the resulting SOAPEnvelope get the value.
```

here in this url, you can see the nature of the soap request and response when interacting with this webservice..
http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?op=ConversionRate

my java code above, get the right and exact soap response specified in the URL I provided and expected.. but always with the value I need as 0.
This is the soap response I get:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body><ConversionRateResponse 
xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
<ConversionRateResult>0</ConversionRateResult></ConversionRateResponse>
</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

You can see the CoversionRateResult as 0, although it should return 4.69. I tried another webservice they provide and I get aways such result.

Can someone please help me by looking what could be missing in my java code? I tried different variations and keep playing around since a day :( .. and nothing.
I would really appreciate anyone help me in this. 
Thank you,

Comment: your problem could be related to using the `SOAP` element instead of using `soap`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If you meant the one in the string at the beginning of the code (the soap request), I just tried it out and I got the following error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "soap" for element "soap:Envelope" is not bound.

Comment: Did you remember to change the xmlns for the soap namespace as well?  Your code above specifies it as `xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">` - also, change everything.  XML is not HTML, and XML parsers are incredibly pedantic.

Comment: If I understood you right, I just added a QName object to the Service Call.. and its still the same result.. If this is not what you meant by your suggestion, I would really appreciate if you post your suggested modification of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct string passed in my above example, which worked is:

```
String SOAP_REQUEST = 
"<soapenv:Envelope 
     xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"
     xmlns:web=\"http://www.webserviceX.NET/\">
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
 <web:ConversionRate>
 <web:FromCurrency>EUR</web:FromCurrency>
 <web:ToCurrency>ILS</web:ToCurrency>
 </web:ConversionRate>
 </soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>"
```

Just in case anyone encountered this issue.. my reputation does not allow me to mark it as correct.
And many thanks to mcfinnigan for helping me out..

Comment: If anyone has a problem in this, ask please.. I already spent sometime on this issue.. Also I have built a corresponding SOAPEnvelope object representing this or similar request(s)..

Answer (score 0):

Try with this XML

```
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" 
    xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" 
    xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">
    <soap:Body><ConversionRate xmlns=\"http://www.webserviceX.NET/\"/>
    <FromCurrency>EUR</FromCurrency>
    <ToCurrency>ILS</ToCurrency>
    </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks again for keeping with me in this matter. It did unfortunately produce the same output.. with 0 value for ConversionRateResult.. I am suspecting it might be in the java code I provided or something missing maybe? really appreciate if you can have a look again.. this fault is killing my day(s)..

Comment: Unfortunately I'm behind a corporate firewall so I can't write code and actually test the remote web service.  Can you not get a copy of soapUI and use that to test that the service is working correctly when you access it?

Comment: I just tried it with soapUI and it worked.. The only difference in the request I could see is `soapenv:Envelope` instead of my `soap:Envelope`.. 
And also in soapUI, there is `web:ConversionRate` instead of my `web:ConversionRate`
could that be something?

Comment: Probably the service stub on the remote side is expecting the exact XML, and soapUI is good at that.  Try with the xml generated by soapUI in your java program.

Comment: This exception is a friend of mine today: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "web" for element "web:FromCurrency" is not bound. Everytime I change/try out something around, another prefix gets this exception...
I think I will give up on this and give it an hour to try to build the request by its appropriate objects not as a string..

Comment: Finally, I have the right form that worked! I will post it after 3 hours as stackoverflow wants me to. Thanks mcfinnigan for the help!